# How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in R language

Tags: r, binary, integer

How to Generate a function in R that translates integers into a binary vector for length K, for example, if I have integer n=3 and length is K= 7

the output is 0000011?
I generate this function but I don't know how to get 0-padded binary representation :

```
convert_to_b <- function(n) 
{
  if(n > 1) {
  convert_to_b(as.integer(n/2))
  }  
  cat(n %% 2)
 }
```

Comment: Suggestion: edit your post title to include the programming language in the title it might improve your chances at an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `R.utils` package has the function `intToBin()` that can be combined with `sprintf()` to left pad the result.

```
convert_to_b <- function(n, K)
{
  n <- R.utils::intToBin(n)
  if (K < nchar(n))
    K <- nchar(n)
  sprintf("%0*d", K, as.integer(n))
}

convert_to_b(3, 7)
[1] "0000011"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `intToBits`:

```
convert_to_b <- function(n, K) {
    x <- head(substr(intToBits(n), 2L, 2L), K)
    paste(rev(x), collapse="")
}
convert_to_b(3, 7)
#[1] "0000011"
```